# How to get only those data which have particular code in crossfilter

Tags: d3.js, dc.js, crossfilter

I have the following dataset

```
var data=
[
{code:501, value:25},
{code:501, value:30},
{code:501, value:30},
{code:501, value:35},
{code:501, value:60},
{code:502, value:25},
{code:502, value:25}
]
```

I want to get back only the dataset that contains only the data with code 501.
I tried the following code

```
var ndx=crossfilter(data);
var dim1=ndx.dimension(function(d){return d.code});
var filtereddata=dim1.filter(501);
```

But its not working. Its not returning me the data I want. I tried to print the returned data using console but it printed some vague things.

Comment: The filter function returns the same dimension object, not the filtered data. This will filter the data so that any *other* dimensions will see only the 501s.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
function getData(){
  var range = $("#range").val()*1;
  if(isNaN(range)){
    alert("Kindly Enter Valid Number");
  }else{
    var data=
[
{code:501, value:25},
{code:501, value:30},
{code:501, value:30},
{code:501, value:35},
{code:501, value:60},
{code:502, value:25},
{code:502, value:25}
];

var ndx=crossfilter(data);
var dim1=ndx.dimension(function(d){return d.code});
var filtereddata=dim1.filter(range);
    alert("Requested Data is\n"+(JSON.stringify(dim1.top(Infinity))));
}
  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/crossfilter/1.3.11/crossfilter.js"></script>
<input type='text' id='range'>
<input type='button' value='getData' onclick='getData()'>
```

I think you are looking for this....
:D

Comment: For Sample Enter your 501